# tuneup.js reports "Can't find variable" for test() method

Tags: xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

`enter code here`Because I can't get pass/fail logging to work correctly with the 4.6 version of Instruments, I'm trying to use the [tuneup.js](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js) library, but I keep getting the following error whenever I try to run the test:

```
Can't find variable: test
```

Here's the code:

```
//We want to use the tuneup library to add extra capabilities
#import <tuneup_js/tuneup.js>
#import <tuneup_js/test.js>

var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp();

test("Test1", function(target, app) {

//Do UI automation stuff

var titleDisplayed = tableView.cells()[0].name();
var StoryName = "My Dogs!";

UIALogger.logMessage("My Story Title: " + titleDisplayed);
UIALogger.logMessage("Innocuous Message-1.");


assertEquals(titleDisplayed, StoryName); 

}); // <------Error points to this line!

//End test
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The tuneup.js library is in a folder called tuneup_js which is in the root of the directory which contains my test script (an Instruments trace file), and I don't get any import errors on start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Instruments cant find the *tuneup_js* library so it doesn't find the *test* function .You need to add the imports in quotes and you dont need to add `tuneup_js/test.js` because `tuneup_js/tuneup.js` includes all the classes needed

```
//We want to use the tuneup library to add extra capabilities
#import "tuneup_js/tuneup.js"


var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp();

test("Test1", function(target, app) {

//Do UI automation stuff

var titleDisplayed = tableView.cells()[0].name();
var StoryName = "My Dogs!";

UIALogger.logMessage("My Story Title: " + titleDisplayed);
UIALogger.logMessage("Innocuous Message-1.");


assertEquals(titleDisplayed, StoryName); 

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! But when I use quotes I get an "Import file not found" error. This is why I used the <> symbols. When I use the <>, there's no import error. I'm using Xcode 4.6, are you using 4.6 as well?

Comment: Yes I'm also using 4.6.You need to use quotes to import the files, make sure that the path is correct to the tuneup_js files. I think it should be tuneup/tuneup.js

Comment: I also want to add, for those who are trying to chain test multiple tests (e.g. test1.js, test2.js, test3.js ... ) put the #import "tuneup/tuneup.js" inside your Queue javascript file instead of the individual files (Instruments isn't very good at resolving #imports). So for example, lets say I have queue.js that does #import test1.js .... test50.js, I should first put #import "tuneup/tuneup.js" before I #import test1.js inside my queue.js file. Hope that makes sense.