# import tuneup.js file not found

Tags: xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Using the Xcode iOS Instruments UI Automation tuneup.js javascript library https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js .

I'm having challenges understanding the current working diretory of my launched instrument.

I have not been able to make a relative path to the tuneup/tuneup.js script. The destination of the relative path is *of course* "tuneup/tuneup.js".  But what is the starting point?

Here's the code:

```
// This works:

#import "/Users/mikes/Documents/Full/Path/To/File/Tests/tuneup/tuneup.js"

// These do not work:
//#import "tuneup/tuneup.js"
//#import "Tests/tuneup/tuneup.js"


//
// See https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js
//

test("First Screen", function(target, app) {

     var window = app.mainWindow();

     window.logElementTree();

});
```

See [tuneup.js reports "Can't find variable" for test() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304933/tuneup-js-reports-cant-find-variable-for-test-method) for a related question.

-Thanks

-Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that the reason this isn't working is because you created an embedded script in the Instruments document. Instead of choosing "Add > Create Script" in the sidebar of instruments, you need to choose "Add > Import" and import your script file from the file system. That will link the Instruments document to your script file and when you use the `#import` keyword, it will look in the directory *relative to where your script file resides*.

Embedded (as opposed to imported) scripts do not have a "current directory" which is why you need to absolute path to the `tuneup.js` file.