# In Xcode Instruments, how to import a UIAutomation script?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, ui-automation

In Xcode Instruments, how to #import a UIAutomation script that is listed under the "Scripts" section?

In the **currentFile.js**, I tried doing `#import "functionsToImport.js"`. It didn't work, so I moved the file to my desktop and changed the import to `#import "~/desktop/fcns.js"` but neither of the solutions works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Choose **Automation -> Add -> Import** and import your script file from the file system.

Doing like so will link the Instruments document to your script file, so when you use the `#import` keyword, it will look in the directory relative to where your script file resides.

Note that you have to import both js files to Instruments to work properly.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me. Gave multiple popup alerts saying: An Error Occured - The #import file 'functions.js' was not found, as required from the script 'Live2BenchUIAutomationTests.trace'

Comment: Found the solution. The original file doing the import has to be imported from the file system as well and not created with the Instruments app. <[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387150/import-tuneup-js-file-not-found)>

Comment: Solved the issue for me as well (importing BOTH js files to Instruments)!  Still a problem in XCode 7.2