# iOS Instruments Automation - Including files not working

Tags: ios, user-interface, testing, automation, instruments

this may be a stupid question, but while starting to write some automation code for an iOS app I cannot get including files to work. Here's what I do:

- I generate a new project in Instruments based on the Automation template and save it as "MyAutomation.trace"
- I create a new script called `Utils.js` and add some reusable code to it
- In the main script I try to include the Utils.js by adding `#import "Utils.js"` at the beginning of the file.

When running the main script I get the error:

`The #import file 'Utils.js' was not found, as required from the script 'MyAutomation.trace'`

I've tried putting the file to an external folder, importing it and using different absolute and relative paths. The Utils.js is in the same directory as the trace file. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths work with imports. Try using `#import "./Utils.js"`

`./` points to current directory, `../` points to parent directory.

The Utils.js file should be in the same folder as your test script, not the .trace file

Comment: Rereading your question I honestly don't think the `./` is necessary but i'm not sure, what you need to do is save your test somewhere and put the Utils.js in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to create a .js file manually, then add it to the Instruments workspace using Add->Import
That way the script file will have a defined location for the relative paths to refer.
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391153/5118854

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here.
Only absolute paths work, i.e.:

```
#import "/Users/USERNAME/git/your_repo/Pods/tuneup_js/tuneup.js"
```

I tried all sorts of things, but only this one works so far.
Unfortunately you can't run such test on appthwack or similar service.